# How can I sort by field position in querydsl?

Tags: mysql, querydsl

In JPQL I can use the following `select u from Entity u order by u.field1, 1`.
This ensures that the back-end mysql database will always return the result in the exact same order (e.g. in case `u.field1` has duplicates).
At position 1 I always keep the PK(id).

How can I achieve the same (use positional sorting) with `querydsl`?

P.S. Sorting code is dynamically generated, so I want to avoid the requirement to provide the PK as an extra parameter to the SortUtil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your requirement is to order by a database column, then by a number you provide as an argument. I think this will work, I've passed `1L` into `Expressions.constant` but obviously replace this with your dynamically generated field.

```
.orderBy(someRelationalPathBase.field1.asc(), new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, Expressions.constant(1L)))
```